# Select toolBar items from another controller

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a toolBar in my WindowViewController and when I click on an item, I want to switch to the right tab in next controller which is a TabViewController.

How to do that ? there is no rootviewcontroller like in iOS so I can't get the toolBar items from my TabViewController. Thanks

[image]

btw, if you ask me why I'm using toolbar + tabView that's because I want a tabView with a custom tab items. So I make my own custom toolbar in interface builder and then I will hide the tab items of the tabView. Hope it's the good choice.

***********  EDIT  **********

I can remove the tabView and get a containerView if it is better, but the question will be almost the same : How I can switch to the View1 when I press the button1 and view2 when I press the button2 ?

[image]

Comment: Fix my issue, thanks to the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219441/how-to-use-nstoolbar-in-xcode-6-and-storyboard/24810534?noredirect=1#comment38523066_24810534